# Can I directly traverse this linked list using just the head pointer?

Tags: c, function, data-structures, linked-list, pass-by-value

I've just started DSA recently and this question may seems trivial, but big thanks to those who take it seriously. This is my program:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};

typedef struct node node;
    
void printNodes(node* head) {
    if(head == NULL)
        printf("Linked list is empty");
    node *ptr = head;
    while(ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->link;
    }
}

int main() {
    node *head = NULL;
    head = malloc(sizeof(node));
    head->data = 3;
    head->link = NULL;

    node *current = NULL;
    current = malloc(sizeof(node));
    current->data = 4;
    current->link = NULL;
    head->link = current;
        
    current = malloc(sizeof(node));
    current->data = 5;
    current->link = NULL;
    head->link->link = current;
    
    printNodes(head);
}
```

I have the function below to **traverse and print the data of nodes in the linked list**:

```c
void printNodes(node *head) {
    if(head == NULL)
        printf("Linked list is empty");
    node *ptr = NULL;
    ptr = head;
    while(ptr != NULL){
        printf("%d ", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->link;
    }
}
```

I think the code works just fine if we don't use the `node* ptr`:

```c
void printNodes(node *head) {
    if(head == NULL)
        printf("Linked list is empty");
    while(head != NULL){
        printf("%d ", head->data);
        head = head->link;
    }
}
```

Please tell me if my there is any problem in my thought.

Comment: There is no question here. Please: (1) specify what exactly the problem is (2) how that problem can be reproduced -- provide the code that calls this function (3) how you have used a debugger to analyse the problem (4) tag the question with the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As the pointer `head` that points to the first node of the list is passed to the function by value that is the function deals with a copy of the value of the pointer `head` then the function is unable to change the original pointer `head` declared in main.

In this case the pointer `ptr` may be removed from the function definition.

Pay attention that as the function does not change the list itself then its parameter should be declared with qualifier `const` as for example

```
void printNodes( const node *head )
{
    if ( head == NULL )
    {
        printf("Linked list is empty");
    }
    else
    {
        while ( head != NULL )
        {
            printf("%d ", head->data);
            head = head->link;
        }
    }
}
```